# modify user login screen details (gdm)

Tags: debian, users, login, gdm

I have a single linux desktop at home, with every member of the family having their own user name / login combo (shared external drive for sharing pics, docs etc).

I have realised that the GDM login screen shows the username for some and the 'full name' for others.
e.g. for me it shows 'David Myers' (my full name, obviously), for my wife it shows helenm (her log in).

In the most part this is not a problem, but I would like for it to be consistent between all users. I've clearly done something different when creating the users (which I did via the command line).

Using

```
sudo users-admin
```

the application refuses to open up , but on the basic version (non root) all the details seem the same (obviously I can't view the advanced details).

What I would like, is for it to display the login name in a larger bold font, followed by the full name in a smaller font in parenthesis. Is this possible (I'm sure it is)?

Pertinent details:

- OS : Debian - jessy.
- desktop : XFCE
- login screen : GDM (to allow user switching, and I can confirm that the system takes much longer to boot up to GDM rather than the native XFCE version).

Answer (score 0):

Try editing form the command line.

You can change it with user mod -c option. -c is for adding comment.

```
usermod -c "YOUR NAME" username
```

Comment: I've tried this and the information in the finger for the user doesn't change? and the login screen remains the same also. Also the finger results is the same for all users, so I'm not sure what is different.